# Find amount of records in table that are not modified for long time

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle 10g. I want to find the amount of records in a particular table that have not been modified(insert or update) for past 2 years.

But the table do not have a date column. I need to find it from database options. Is there a way I can find this?

Comment: Without a `datetime` or `date` or `timestamp` column it's not possible. Though in 10g you have a feature `ORA_ROWSCAN` but 2 years old data ... don't think so.

Comment: Only option seems to be that you check your audit information. Flashback is no option for two year old data (if not configured for that) and [ORA_ROWSCN](http://psoug.org/reference/pseudocols.html) only shows the last update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it for individual rows, but you can do it for database blocks. Dump the individual database blocks and determine the scn of the last change of each block and then use the scn_to_timestamp function to het time of the last change to the block.

If the none of the rows in this data block has been modified you will get accurate information. If however a single row is changed, you cannot use this method to determine if the other rows in that block haven't been changed for the last two years.

Comment: You'll still run into problems with [SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions161.htm#BABEHBCB): "The association between an SCN and a timestamp when the SCN is generated is remembered by the database for a limited period of time."